# My time picker is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi friends my time picker is not working please some one help me

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js">    </script>       
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../src/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $('.time').each(function () {
           $('.time').timepicker({
               hourGrid: 4,
               minuteGrid: 10,
               timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt'
           });
       });
   });
```

Comment: timepicker is not a part of jquery ui, you need to include the corresponding plugin library

Comment: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ -  http://www.ama3.com/anytime/

Comment: Also you're doing unnecessary loop using $('.time').each(...). $('.time').timepicker() should create pickers on all 'time' class elements. You shouldn't loop them by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `timepicker` library in your html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js">
</script>       

<!-- Add this script tag -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="[timepicker_LOCATION]/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js">
</script>
```

https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Timepicker-Addon

**Note:** Also there is no need to loop through to each `.time` class

**Remove the loop**

```
$('.time').each(function ()
```